# Inhomogeneous integral equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-integrals

Let $g$ be a nonnegative Borel-measurable function, that is locally integrable
on $[0, \infty)$. Assume that $g$ satisfies for all $t \geq 0$ the inequality $g(t) \leq a + b \int^t_0 g(s) ds$, where $a, b \geq 0$. I want to show that $g(t) \leq ae^{bt}$.

A hint to me was given that I should solve the inhomogeneous integral equation
$$g(t) = a + b\int^t_0 g(s) ds − p(t)$$
for a nonnegative function $p$. But I have no clue how I should prove this and how this helps me proving the first statement. Thanks for any hints and help.

A little context; this is a question asked in a stochastic integration course but I don't see a real connection here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This inequality is called the Grownwall inequality in the ode theory. Following the hint, you may compute the first order derivative of the both sides of the inhomogeneous integral equation, and convert the integral equation to an ordinary diffrential equation. Then you can solve the ODE and obtain the analytic solution.
The following is another way to show the inequality. First we let
$$ G\left(t\right)=\int_{0}^{t}g\left(s\right)ds $$
Substitute this equation into the inequality
$$ G'\left(t\right)\le a+bG\left(t\right) $$
Multiply by $ \exp\left(-bt\right) $

$$ \frac{d \left(\exp\left(-bt\right)G\left(t\right)\right)}{dt} \le a\exp\left(-bt\right) $$
\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned}
\exp\left(-bs\right)G\left(s\right)\Big|_{s=0}^{s=t} & \le -\frac{a}{b}exp\left(-bs\right)\Big|_{s=0}^{s=t} \\ &= \frac{a}{b}\left(1-\exp\left(-bt\right) \right) 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Integrate the inequality
$$ G\left(t\right) \le \frac{a}{b}\left(exp\left(bt\right)-1\right) $$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
g\left(t\right) & \le a+bG\left(t\right) \\ & \le a\exp\left(bt\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: Some words would be nice (and make it easier to follow). Looks correct though.

Comment: I don't see how to obtain the second inequality after submitting. Could you explain how to perform it?

Comment: I have one issue with the first step, namely to perform it we need to have a function $g$ that is **continuous**.

Comment: see Real Analysis, Royden, Page 102
Lemma: if $f$ is bounded and measurable on $[a,b]$ and
$ F(x) = \int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt+F(a) $, then $ F'(x) = f(x) $ for almost all $x$ in $[a,b]$.
and Page 103
Theorem: Let $f$ be an integrable function on $[a,b]$, and suppose
$$F(x) = F(a)+\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt $$
Then $F'(x)=f(x)$ for almost all $x$ in $[a,b]$.